# How do you say "probably''?

Tags: translation

How do you say "probably" in Chinese as in: "probably we will start having lessons next month"......can you use 可能 or 有可能? Can you give me an example of where these are placed in a sentence and how they are used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

我们下个月肯定开始上课. 100%

**我们下个月开始上课. 90%  as the base.**

我们下个月很可能开始上课. 80%

我们下个月有可能开始上课. 70%

**我们下个月可能开始上课. 50% as a middle base for not sure.**

我们下个月好像不能开始上课. 40%

我们下个月不太可能开始上课. 30%

我们下个月不可能开始上课. 20%

**我们下个月肯定不能开始上课. 0%**

Sorry, the Chinese is really messy, isn't it? Those numbers are just for reference, please do not take it too much seriously.

Answer (score 4):

For "Maybe‘ in Chinese we can say 可能，或许,也许

1.You use it as abverb to modify the whole sentence.

Probably, You don't like him, you just like his money. 
或许,你喜欢的不是他这个人，而是他的钱。 
Maybe you are right！也许,你说的对！

2.You use it before verbs to modify the verbs.

You probably get pregnant! 你可能怀孕了！
Maybe you forget your promise! 你或许忘了你的誓言吧。

Comment: 我们 下个月 可能 上课.
Is this correct?
Where can I use "有可能"？

Comment: again easily answered by online dictionaries，e。g。iciba ，which has plenty of sample sentences showing exact meaning，just enter 有可能 in dictionary and the
句库 part will provide lots of sample sentences
通过查看在线词典，比如爱词霸对这样问题一下子就可以得到所需要的信息。作为其中一个爱词霸有大量的例句说明各个词语的使用范围。只需要把＂有可能＂输入词典，而词典的句库就会提供要多少就有多少例句。